# How to call different database for different user as per some group stored in file in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var database = require('./bootstrap/database');
req.dbPool = database.pool;
req.dbquery = database.query;
req.cacheData = require('./bootstrap/cache')(req.dbPool);
req.nosql = mongoose;
next();  });
```

### I want to load different database for the different user.

#### How can implement this?

Suppose, User A belongs to group 1 and User B belongs to group 2.
When User A comes to site and try to log in, it requests to Database A1 and when user comes to site and try to log in, it requests to Database B2.

Answer (score 0):

When your user logs in, your server will presumably set a cookie for that user.  You can then use that cookie in your `app.use()` middleware to identify which user is making the request and set the appropriate database for that user into the `req` object.  Then, when your actual route handler fires, you will have the appropriate database already available for that user in the `req` object.

If the group for a given user is constant, you can look that up just once when the user logs in and either set that in a separate cookie (probably encrypted so it can't be messed with) or if you are using a session manager to keep track of logged in state, you can set the appropriate database reference or group identifier into the user's session.  Then, when the middleware fires, it can find the right session object for this user and retrieve the information about which group they are in.

If the group is dynamic, then you make have to look up the group for this user on every request.

Comment: how can we change db name while node server is already started. It may require to restart node server, so that new config can be load in node server